# Should system path & user path match?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems, environment-variables, path

This morning I was trying to add python to my windows 7 PATH and used:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\python34\" /M
```

This seems to have changed my path but not in the manner I'd hoped!

My user path now matches my system path (though is truncated). Python does not seem to have been added on either path.

Am I correct in thinking my user path should be different to my system path?

If so, how can I recover my user path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realised as I'd just installed python that there would be a system restore point from that, so I rolled back to that point. Job done

After the restore, the two paths do appear to be different. When I run `echo %PATH%` in the command prompt The result is the system path concatenated with the user path.